# Correct way to put node_modules/.bin on PATH for WebStorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm for a fairly straightforward project using Node, NPM, and Gulp. One of my Gulp tasks ends up doing `gulp lint` in a subprocess, and unless I have `gulp` on my `PATH`, I get

```
[14:20:37] Starting 'lint-parallel'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn gulp ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

So my question: what's the correct way to set up WebStorm so `node_modules/.bin` is on my `PATH`? I ended up setting `PATH` in Gulp Settings → Environment to `node_modules/.bin:<rest of path>`, but it felt very manual for pretty basic behavior. Or should I have `PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH` in my shell profile and let WebStorm pick it up that way?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm inherits your interactive shell environment when being started from terminal, and uses environment variables configured in `~/.profile` (login shell) when launched from Desktop or System menu. So you need to make sure that `node_modules/.bin` is added to your `$PATH` in the corresponding config to get it picked up

Comment: Is adding `node_modules/.bin` the canonical way of doing this in general?

Comment: I'd say - no: binaries from local node_modules should not normally be on your system `$PATH`; Gulp cli is usually installed globally - this is a requirement, and `<npm_prefix>/bin` is normally on your `$PATH`

Comment: "in the corresponding config" ? How? Where is it? Is it a WebStorm setting?

Comment: `.bash_profile` or `.profile` or whatever file your login shell configuration is stored in; and no, it's not a webstorm configuration, these are your OS files